# Error while traversing through a char array to find numeric values

Tags: arrays, c

I am writing a function that takes input from the user as a character array and checking to see the amount of numbers present while summing them (eg 0123456789 would be count=10, sum=45)

The problem is that if a user inputs something like 'welcome to 123 street' count and sum are both 0. when the output should be count=3, sum=6.

The method I am using is to check to see if the index of the char array is greater than or equal to zero AND less than or equal to 9 (ASCII values).

Here is the code for the function:

```
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

void num_count(char array[]) {
  while (array[i] != '\0') {
    if (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9') {
        count++;
        sum += (array[i] - '0');
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

not sure if I need to post my main function.

Comment: What does "not sure if main function is needed" mean? You need a `main()` function for your C code to start somewhere.

Comment: What "error" do you get? Please **be specific** and include the *exact* text you get. Have you stepped through this code in a debugger with that sample input to see what it actually does?

Comment: @tadman I don't get an error, its that the output of the function is incorrect

Comment: When using the term "error" keep in mind it means specifically "program produced an error" not "program didn't do thing I wanted".

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling the function several times, and the variables `i`, `count` and `sum`, being defined in the global scope, are not reinitialised.

Try:

```
int count = 0;
int sum = 0;

void num_count(char *array) {
  int i;
  count = 0;
  sum   = 0;
  for (i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++) {
    if (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9') {
        count++;
        sum += (array[i] - '0');
    }
  }
}
```

As @tadman noted, you should not use global variables this way. Since you can only return one value from the function, you could use the other as a parameter:

```
/**
* Function to count digits.
*
* @param  char *     array     array to be counted
* @param  int  *     sum       where the sum is stored
*
* @return int                  number of numeric characters found
*/
int num_count(char *array, int *sum) {
  int i;
  count = 0;
  *sum   = 0;
  for (i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++) {
    if (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9') {
        count++;
        *sum += (array[i] - '0');
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

You would call this as

```
int count, sum;
count = num_count(string, &sum);
printf("Count is %d, sum is %d\n", count, sum);
```

This allows all the code to "live" inside a single function, with no pieces (sum and count) being left dangling and, worse, possibly being overwritten by or conflicting with other functions that need the same variables.

The main module only needs to know how the function is to be called, so (usually in main.h or something of the kind) you would have the function's *prototype* with maybe a description:

int num_count(char *array, int *sum);

Comment: Those should all be moved local to the function, presumably. Having them as globals is a bad habit to get into anyway.

Comment: this function is defined in a file outside of main, so I need to export that variable to be able to use the value received back to main, at least that's what my professor told us.

Comment: This is correct, but you only really need the prototype of the function; the other variables, in the second example, either "live" only in the function (this is the case for i ) or are returned by the function (this is what happens with count) or are passed by reference. The variables are defined in main, and passed to the module outside of main.